# how to perfectly center an icon image inside a <div>

Tags: html, css

I had an icon img and was trying to center it inside a card div but is somehow not working. I already tried `text-align: center;` and `display:flex; justify-content: center;` and both did not help. I attached my code below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 3%;
  right: 0.5%;
}

.card:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ccc;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px lighten(#000, 60%);
  transition: box-shadow .2s ease-in-out;
}

.card.level-1:hover:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 80px lighten(#000, 60%);
}

.card level-1 img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="card level-1">
  <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/32/000000/microphone--v2.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `margin: auto;` yet? use it by doing something like this: `img {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;  width: 50%;}`

Comment: @maryemneyli No, that is a horrible idea. The tag is deprecated and OP is using flex to handle this

Comment: `card level-1 img {` is not a container either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put flex on the container of the image like this:

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you add that to OP's snippet in your answer. It does not seem to be enough

Comment: I moved it to codePen and it worked for me. Or what do you mean?

Comment: If I paste your code into the snippet I made for OP, it did not seem to work as expected

Comment: Here is mine: https://codepen.io/TenderA/pen/NWdKMjg

Comment: If the idea is to center it horizontally, then it isn't

Comment: If i understood correctly he wanted it centered inside the card not the screen.